# Plot Constant Function in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot some constant functions (horizontal lines) like y=2 and y=5 all in the same plot.

Also, I need to set each axes scale (like x going from 0 to 1 and y from 0 to 20). I need to do the same for x=5 and x=2 (vertical lines) in another plot, but I guess the process should be similar

Here's an image of how the horizontal lines should look (in this case without axes scale)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hlines` is what you are looking for, try the code below

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))

ax.set_ylim(-1,20)
ax.set_xlim(-10,10)

ax.hlines(3,-15,15,color='b')
ax.hlines(5,-15,15,color='b')
```